# Ist "unverbindlicher" hier ein Adverb?

Tags: adverb, word-classes

Ich frage mich, ob im folgenden Satz:

> Da die meisten Menschen ständig erreichbar sind, fallen Verabredungen heutzutage unverbindlicher aus.

das Wort *unverbindlicher* ein Adverb ist.

Comment: No it's a compared adjective belonging to _Verabredungen_.

Comment: sorry but compare what exactly?

Comment: _"sorry but compare what exactly?"_ _unverbindlich_ to _unverbindlicher_. _Comparing_ is used in the sense of the grammatical term in my comment.

Comment: This question is really interesting because the question is whether *unverbindlicher* is a predicative or an adverb. Unfortunately the comparative obscures this question.

Comment: @Millen I am sorry. This question is amazing and I can't understand why it is considered *off-topic* :(

Comment: @Abdullah I do not understand either!!

Comment: I don't understand either.

Comment: @Millen I don't understand how you could come to the conclusion that _unverbindlicher_ would act as an adverb at all? Could you elaborate about that misconception please?

Comment: unverbindlicher in this sentence is absolutely an adverb. There is no ambiguity. If it were an not an adverb, but an adjective, then you would need to decline it according to gender / number / case. That would give you something like „fallen Verabredungen unzureichendere (Plural!) aus“, which is a complete nonsense.

Comment: As I already wrote, *unverbindlicher* could also be a predicative, as in *Seien Sie unverbindlicher!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Words with the markers **-bar, -ig, -isch, -lich, -los, -sam, -voll** before the ending are most times adjectives made from verbs or nouns.

You can put those adjectives into comparative and superlative as any other adjective. Most of them can take the prefix un- (sometimes in- instead), and of course they borrow the prefixes of the verb they are made of.

> verbinden → verbindlich → unverbindlich, unverbindlicher, am unverbindlichsten
>
> Da die meisten Menschen ständig erreichbar sind, fallen Verabredungen heutzutage unverbindlicher aus.

And yes, this adjective *unverbindlicher* is either used as an adverb or a predicative adjective here. The latter because the meaning of *ausfallen* is *sein* (more exact: to be often/to be in particular) in your example.

> Da die meisten Menschen ständig erreichbar sind, **sind** Verabredungen heutzutage **oft** unverbindlicher.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. 1. Can't be an attributive adjective because if it is an adjective of *Verabredungen*, it should be in nominative *unverbindliche* or *unverbindlichere* (if comparative). 2. Can't be a predicative adjective because there is no *sein, bleiben, werden*. 3. **Adverb** (what I think to be right) from the comparative adjective (unverbindlicher) and means here 'in a way more noncommital'.

Comment: I think it's a corner case because *ausfallen* has the meaning *sein* (more exactly: *to be in particular*) in the example sentence. But this difference between adverbs and predicative adjectives isn't of practical use anyway. (At least I don't see one.)

Comment: Abdullah‘s answer has got it right.